# why is audio object giving error 'invalid time value' for toISOString() when audio isn't playing?

Tags: jquery, audio

I have an audio object:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.preload = "auto";
audio.src = "myfile.mp3";
```

When the audio plays, the player should show the time elapsed:

```
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
    // Update the position of the scrubber
    var progress = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * $('#audio_scrubber').width();
    $('#audio_progress').width(progress);

    // Update the time
    $('#audio_time').html(new Date(audio.currentTime * 1000).toISOString().substr(14,5));
    $('#audio_length').html(new Date(audio.duration * 1000).toISOString().substr(14,5));
});
```

This code works fine while the audio is playing, but when you first load the page, it throws this error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value
at Date.toISOString (<anonymous>)
at Audio.<anonymous> (script.js:350)
```

I don't understand -- shouldn't the addEventListener code only fire when the audio is playing?